# Intent-Filter implementation for customized file Extensions on Xamarin

Tags: android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to open files with customized extensions in my app. It can come from email, downloads, Bluetooth etc. Whenever user taps on those files my application should open and perform some tasks.  I need a reference/help for xamarin platform. I am literally new in this.

My android menifest

```
<activity android:name=".StartFileActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="com.ppp.androidintentfile" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="https"  android:host="com.ppp.androidintentfile" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file"  android:host="com.ppp.androidintentfile" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.IE3" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Activity Code

```
namespace AndroidIntentFile
{
[Activity (Label = "StartFileActivity")]
[IntentFilter(new[]{Intent.ActionSend},Categories = new[]{Intent.CategoryDefault},DataMimeType = "application/*",Label = "AndroidIntentFile")]  

public class StartFileActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend && Intent.Extras.ContainsKey(Intent.ExtraStream))
        {
            var fileUrl = GetFilePath((Android.Net.Uri)Intent.Extras.GetParcelable(Intent.ExtraStream));
        }
    }

    private string GetFilePath(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        return uri.ToString ();
    }
}


}
```

Getting below error

> Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ppp.androidintentfile/com.ppp.androidintentfile.StartFileActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ppp.androidintentfile.StartFileActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ppp.androidintentfile-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ppp.androidintentfile-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using class attributes and without making any hardcoded manifest additions:

```
[Activity(Label = "StartFileActivity")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "application/*", DataPathPattern = "*.IE3")]
public class StartFileActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Do something with the *.IE3 file...
    }
}
```

Will automatically add to your manifest:

```
<activity android:label="StartFileActivity" android:name="md54385a510f3a446695f2c9f6ad6a86f05.StartFileActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="*.IE3" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you really need to remove the auto-generated name, provide a hard-code `Activity` name:

```
[Activity(Label = "StartFileActivity", Name="foo.bar.SomeName")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "application/*", DataPathPattern = "*.IE3")]
public class StartFileActivity : Activity
```

Results in:

```
<activity android:label="StartFileActivity" android:name="foo.bar.SomeName">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="*.IE3" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: That worked !!! I knew i was missing something in the class attribute. Thanks @SushiHangover

Comment: Can you add the code that's required to actually access the `*.IE3` file?